# Bootstrap 6-column responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a Bootstrap layout for my design and am about to make it responsive and saving needed order. For example the such as this:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2" >div1</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2" >div2</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2" >div3</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2" >div4</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2" >div5</div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2" >div6</div>
</div>
```

On md – viewports I’ll get like this:

```
div1 div2 div3 div4 div5 div6
```

On sm- viewports:

```
div1 div2 div3
div4 div5 div6
```

How could I reorder columns to get like this on sm-viewports:

```
div1 div3 div5
div2 div4 div6
```

In others words – every even columns have to go down, and every odd column have to stay up. Is it possible?

Answer (score 9):

Simply introduce a new set of columns:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" >div1</div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" >div2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" >div3</div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" >div4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" >div5</div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" >div6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DTLLu/).

Comment: @user3292126 no worries. Please remember to mark this as the accepted answer to close the question when you get the chance. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Using [the `col-*-push-N` and `col-*-pull-N` column ordering classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) should do the trick:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2" >div1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-md-push-2" >div3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-md-push-6" >div5</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-md-pull-4" >div2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-md-pull-4" >div4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-2" >div6</div>
</div>
```

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eakfH